# Is it possible to add a bounty to your own question, after creation?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounty

I see the option to add a bounty to other poster's questions, but not to my own. By design? Am I missing something?

Sorry if this is covered elsewhere. I did look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, your questions are no different from anyone else's for the purpose of bounty.

See https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty

Pay *very very close* attention to the rules at the bottom of that section!

(also note that any bounties you have offered now or in the past are on the bounty tab on your user page.)

Comment: Thanks. It was the must be 2 days old part that got me. I was seeing the link on other questions, but not mine.

Comment: Further question: What happens if a bounty is not awarded manually, in a situation where the bounty is offered after an answer has been accepted by the OP. The highest upvoted answer and the accepted answer are different. Who gets the bounty? Example here: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/5076/1259

Comment: that is specifically answered in the last bullet point in the faq link. Generally speaking accepted answer is mostly irrelevant for bounty, though we do assume *if you accept an answer **during** the bounty period*, but fail to award the bounty, we'll award it to the accepted answer at the end of the 7 day bounty period. But not relevant to that Q, since there is already an accepted answer, and also because the bounty owner is not the question owner anyway.